# Filtering next select box's value depending on what is selected in the first select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have select boxes in which values are getting appended dynamically thru an array.
Now suppose if i have 4 values in my 1st select box, then i want only 3 values in the 2nd select box excluding the value that has already been selected in the 1st select box.

now there will be 3 values in 2nd select box and if i select a value then the 3rd select box will have only 2 values excluding the one already selected in 2nd select box and so on...

please help on how should i filter

Comment: Show us what you did so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Vbyec/6yp3C/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var array = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
var temp;

new_select();

function new_temp() {
    temp = "";
    temp += '<option value="null"></option>';
    array.forEach(function (entry, index) {
        temp += '<option value="' + index + '">' + entry + '</option>';
    });
}

function new_select() {
    if (array.length > 0) {
        new_temp();
        $('.result').append('<select class="mine_select">' + temp + '</select>');
        $(".mine_select").change(function () {
            array.splice($(this).val(), 1);
            new_select();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if i select first in 1st select then again if i wanna select value second in 1st select.. then it is not populating value accordingly